# Keeping track of connected user with socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, user-tracking

I need to keep tracks of users connection, disconnection and login time.
I use sockets for this but I am troubled over some stuff.
For now I created an array that keeps track of connection and disconnection from user.

Something like

> const connectedUser = [];

So this is initialised at the launch of my server, and I add/delete values continuously.

Is there a better way to track what I want ?

For now I have like a few thousands users, so it's not that huge. But I question this in term of scalability. For like a 100k users, i'm not sure this would be the proper way to handle this issue.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you !

Edit:
My app is Trello-like. Users can create/like/comment "issues".
They can also see which user is connected and send dm.

So what I implemented served this purpose -> See who is connected in real time and send messages.

I thought that this data is volatil, there is no purpose to store this data. So that's why I use array.
Wouldn't it be a waste of storage to store this data ?

Comment: Use... any database if you need durable and scalable storage? I'd recommend Redis or Postgres. It's hard to tell what you're actually doing based on your post though.

Comment: That is, can you please expand on what your app is or does? Clients connect to a server, but what are "users" here? What do they do?

Comment: My app is Trello-like. Users can create/like/comment "issues".
They can also see which user is connected and send dm.

So what I implemented served this purpose -> See who is connected in real time and send messages.

I thought that this data is volatil, there is no purpose to store this data. So that's why I use array.
Wouldn't it be a waste of storage to store this data ?

I imagined to have a "user state" in db, and update this value upon connection/disconnection to the socket. But isn't this less efficient (speed-wise) ?

Comment: If you store the data only in an array within your server process, you can't scale to multiple server processes, for one. But if the data really is volatile, then I'd recommend Redis.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and your time, I will look into it !